# How to show that a set is a sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, borel-sets

I need help with this problom:

Let $A={\{E\in \mathcal B(R) | E =  -E}\}$

That is the collection of symmetric borel measurable sets with respect to origin

I have to show that A is $\sigma-algebra$ over $A$

Comment: Do you know what a $\sigma-$algebra is ?... If so, you just have to check the axioms one by one.